# Join double records

Tags: mysql, sql

hi I have a little problem with query

```
questions
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     id    |  question_id |  question |right_answer | question_type |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    500       |  string   |     a       |     1,2       |
|     2     |    600       |  string   |     b       |     1,2,3     |
|     3     |    620       |  string   |     c       |    3,1,2      |
|     4     |    750       |  string   |     c       |     4,1       |
|     5     |    800       |  string   |     b       |     5,1       |
|     6     |    900       |  string   |     a       |      1        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
users_answers
--------------------------------------------------------
|     id    |  question_id2 |  user_id | question_true |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |     500       |    2     |      1        |
|     2     |     500       |    1     |      1        |
|     3     |     600       |    2     |      1        |
|     4     |     600       |    1     |      1        |
|     5     |     900       |    1     |      1        |
|     6     |     800       |    2     |      1        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

```
category
---------------------------------------------
|     id    |  question_id3 |  category_id  |
---------------------------------------------
|     1     |     500       |       1       |
|     2     |     600       |       1       |
|     3     |     620       |       1       |
|     4     |     750       |       1       |
|     5     |     800       |       1       |
|     6     |     900       |       1       |
---------------------------------------------
```

```
SELECT category.*, questions.*, users_answers.* FROM category
LEFT JOIN questions ON category.question_id3 = questions.question_id
LEFT JOIN users_answers ON category.question_id3 = users_answers.question_id2
WHERE question_type LIKE '%1%' AND category_id = 1
order by case when user_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end, questions.id ASC
```

Now I become 8 result but there is only a 6 questions. I know that problem is join. id1, id2 questions are double (two answers)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b108/3

Comment: Please include actual and expected output so we know what you're looking for. It's not obvious as is.

Comment: Every user (users_answers.user_id) should recive first questions without HIS answers then others questions (users_answers.question_true).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PQtV3Zt6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT category.*, questions.*, users_answers.* 
FROM category
 LEFT JOIN questions ON category.question_id3 = questions.question_id 
LEFT JOIN users_answers ON category.question_id3 = users_answers.question_id2
```

```
order by case when user_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end, questions.id ASC
```

it works fine but 1 questions many answers (users). it's "duplicate" results. Question with id1 and many antworts = result1 ques1,ant1,user1 result2 ques1,ant1,user2 result3 ques1,ant1,user3 help

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42a6c7/1 id1 and id6 are two times displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT category.*, questions.*, users_answers.* FROM category LEFT JOIN questions ON category.question_id3 = questions.question_id LEFT JOIN users_answers ON category.question_id3 = users_answers.question_id2 WHERE users_answers.user_id = 1 ORDER BY question_true ASC


SELECT category.*, questions.*, users_answers.* FROM category LEFT JOIN questions ON category.question_id3 = questions.question_id LEFT JOIN users_answers ON category.question_id3 = users_answers.question_id2 WHERE users_answers.user_id = 2 IS NOT NULL
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdGUn.png

Comment: I need all questions

Comment: please check the second query is ASC order I Hope its work for you

Comment: I recive records WHERE users_answers.user_id = 2 only. I need all records all questions and sort: first questions without answers then questions with answers for every user(users_answers.user_id ) separately.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you're getting all questions and any associated answers.  If a particular question doesn't have an answer, then all of the `users_answers` fields from the `LEFT JOIN` will be `NULL` values.  So you can add any field from `users_answers` to your `ORDER BY`:

```sql
ORDER BY question_true, users_answers.id -- Default sort is ASC
```

This should return questions with no answers (`NULL` values) first.

Comment: I receive all results. I have problem with order by. case of user

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you're trying to do.  You can always include a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` as well, something like `ORDER BY question_true, CASE WHEN users_answers.user_id = $variable_user_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: i have edited main question there are expected results

Comment: Your description of `ORDER BY question_true` doesn't match your `expected for user_id = 1` results.  What does the `question_true` field represent?  One potential issue I see is that you are not referencing a `users` table in your query.  Without this, I believe you will only get info for users' answered questions and not unanswered questions.  If you want to return unanswered questions first, this should do it `ORDER BY users_answers.id`.  To do it for all users, just add the correct `user_id`: `ORDER BY <user_id>, users_answers.id`.

Comment: Sorry this is still very confusing.  Your `questions` table at the top of the page doesn't match the `DDL` in your SQLFiddle.  Are `answer_1, answer_2, answer3` columns in your table or are they fields you want to calculate using a query?  I still have a hard time understanding the exact `ORDER` logic you want.  I suggest you clean up the examples (make them consistent, remove unimportant columns in your `expected` displays, etc).

Comment: ```order by case when user_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end, questions.id ASC ```  it works fine but 1 questions many answers (users). it's "duplicate" results. Question with id1 and many antworts = result1 ques1,ant1,user1 result2 ques1,ant1,user2 result3 ques1,ant1,user3 help http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42a6c7/1